# C-string size including null terminater

Tags: c, cstring

```
 char* str = “ABC\n”;
```

When asked "How many characters are allocated for this string?" why is the answer 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 alphabetic characters + 1 escape character + 1 end of string [`\0`] character

Answer (score 2):

3 bytes for A, B, and C, 1 for the newline and one for the null, aka \0 character.

Answer (score 0):

**3 Albhabets** (ABC) and **one new line** (\n) and **last for null (or end of the string) i.e. \0**.

So the total is five.